# c# messenger, send commands over network, protocol?

Tags: c#

I'm making a c# messenger application just for fun, but I wanna do it good.
I want the possibility to send commands like a chat message, kick comand etc, but i dont know a good way to control it.

I could send an object over the networkstream, or I could send a string like: stream.write("command##");

maybe you know another way to fix this things, but I'm in stackoverflow atm.
Thanks.

Comment: I would use WCF and let Microsoft do all the hard networking work for you.

Comment: To paraphrase an old quote: "Some people, when they have a problem, say, 'I know, I'll use WCF.' Now they have two problems."  I agree, WCF and one of the duplex bindings like Net.TCP is probably the best way to approach this: my point is that MS leaves ya plenty of hard work to do even with WCF.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already have a handle on building your sockets from the use of `Stream.Write()` in your question.

You might want to try something that builds a byte array with a message type, and some sort of checksum. For example:

```
        string message = "this is your message";
        byte packetType = 1;
        byte checksum = 0;

        // calculate a simple checksum
        foreach (char c in message)
        {
            checksum ^= (byte)c;
        }


        // type, message, checksum into buffer
        // (uses list instead of playing with arrays for expeditious example code)
        List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
        buffer.Add(packetType);
        buffer.AddRange(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        buffer.Add(checksum);

        // write out to the socket
        CommStream.Write(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.Count);
```

once you feel adventerous to go beyond sending simple strings, you can attempt serializing objects to byte arrays using the runtime namespace:

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

    public class Message : ISerializable
    {
        DateTime timestamp;
        byte type;
        string message;
    }

    public byte[] BuildBuffer(Message input)
    {
        // Serialize the message
        Stream s = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(s, input);
        buffer = s.ToArray();

        return buffer;
    }

    public Message BuildMessage(byte[] input)
    {
        Stream s = new MemoryStream(input);
        s.Position = 0;

        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (Message)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have some sort of control character (like ) ... when the server sees that character, it starts to record until it receives a space character. Once it hits the space, it looks at the string and compares it against a list of available commands (\kick, etc.).

That's but one technique to tackle this problem. Honestly, if you're doing it for fun, implement it whatever way is the most fun to code :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn your "for fun" project into a "professional development" project (as in, develop your skills, not professional-quality) try WCF.  It will handle the entire messaging architecture for you, and let you focus on your functionality.  Plus, WCF looks good on the resume.